# OnClick redirect depending on radio selection

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple radio list with 6 options.

```
<form>
  <div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" id="EmergencyOption" name="EmergencyOptionradio" value="1">Emergency</label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" id="Non-EmergencyOption" name="Non-EmergencyOptionradio" value="2">Non-Emergency</label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" id="VaccinationOption" name="VaccinationOptionradio" value="3">Vaccination</label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" id="AdviceOption" name="AdviceOptionradio" value="4">Advice</label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" id="BloodTestOption" name="BloodTestOptionradio" value="5">Blood Test</label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" id="FamilyPlanningOption" name="FamilyPlanningOptionradio" value="6">Family Planning</label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="buttonholder">
    <a href="AppType.html"<button type="button" id="submitbtn" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Search</button></a>
  </div>
</form>
```

And a simple button like this:

```
<button type="button" id="submitbtn" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Search</button>
```

I am very new to javascript and am trying to write a function that will listen for the click and then store which value in the radio list is selected. Depending on the selection it will redirect to different pages.

I am trying hard but so far can only come up with bits:

```
document.getElementById("submitbtn").onclick = function () {

//this is some code i have so far
if(selectvalue == "1"){
window.open('***','_self');
return true;
}
else if(selectvalue == "2"){
window.open('***');
return true;
}else if(selectvalue == '3'){
window.open('***');
return true;
}else if(selectvalue == '4'){
window.open('***');
return true;
}


};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, all radio buttons in a set must each have the same value for `name`. That's what groups them together as a set and make their selection mutually exclusive.

Next, rather than arbitrary numbers for each radio button's `value`, give each a value that is descriptive as to what selecting that button signifies.

Next, use **[`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**, instead of an "onXyz" event property to set up your event handling callback functions as this is the modern standard.

Now, when the button is clicked, you need to get the value of the selected radio button and that can be done using a CSS selector with **[`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)**.

Also, `return true;` is not needed in this kind of code.

From there, you just need to compare the value against the known values. You can certainly do this with `if/else if/else` (as you were doing), but since you are checking one thing (the selected radio button's `value`) against several possible values, a **[`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)** statement is a little more appropriate (and some would say elegant). I'm showing both in the code below:

```js
document.getElementById("submitbtn").addEventListener("click", function () {

  // Get selected radio button value
  var selectvalue = document.querySelector("input[name='EmergencyOption']:checked").value;

  var loc = "";
  
  // Find a match with if/else if/else
  /*
  if(selectvalue == "Emergency"){
    loc = "location1.html";
  } else if(selectvalue == "Non-Emergency"){
    loc = "location2.html";
  } else if(selectvalue == 'Vaccination'){
    loc = "location3.html";
  } else if(selectvalue == 'Advice'){
    loc = "location4.html";    
  } else if(selectvalue == 'BloodTest'){
    loc = "location5.html";    
  } else {
    loc = "location6.html";    
  }
  */
  
  // Find a match with switch
  switch(selectvalue){
    case "Emergency":
      loc = "location1.html";
      break;
    case "Non-Emergency":
      loc = "location2.html";
      break;
    case "Vaccination":
      loc = "location3.html";
      break;
    case "Advice":
      loc = "location4.html";
      break;
    case "BloodTest":
      loc = "location5.html";
      break;
    default:
      loc = "location6.html";
      break;      
  }
  
  console.log("navigating to " + loc);
  window.open(loc);
});
```

```css
div.radio { margin-bottom:1em; } /* Create one blank line below each div that has a radio button */
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="EmergencyOption" value="Emergency">Emergency</label>
  </div>

  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="EmergencyOption" value="Non-Emergency">Non-Emergency</label>
  </div>

  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="EmergencyOption" value="Vaccination">Vaccination</label>
  </div>

  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="EmergencyOption" value="Advice">Advice</label>
  </div>

  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="EmergencyOption" value="BloodTest">Blood Test</label>
  </div>

  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="EmergencyOption" value="FamilyPlanning" >Family Planning</label>
  </div>

  <div class="buttonholder">
    <button type="button" id="submitbtn" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**NOTE:**  The `<br>` between `<div>` elements to create some additional vertical spacing is technically an incorrect use for `br`. `br` is for breaking up the content within a block, not for separating blocks. To create that space, a simple CSS rule does the trick.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I very much appreciate the in depth help. I have only started coding last week so it is very much appreciated.

This code works well now and I have learned somwething in the process..

Comment: @GourlayAndrew You're welcome. Be careful learning web development, there is a ton of old, non-standard code out there that (unfortunately) people still use because they don't know any better. Learn and follow the modern standards and good luck! Don't forget to up vote the answer and mark this one as "the" answer.

Comment: I would love to but I dont have enough rep to upvote or vote "the answer. If someone else sees this... this worked really well... please upvote for me :).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a problem in your HTML – those radio buttons must share the same name, otherwise they will not switch (they will act like a regular checkbox). I would stick to Scott's answer, but I think either the if/else and the case switch procedure is unneccessary. I would rather hook to some unique attribute of checked input.

**HTML (quick and dirty copy paste from MDN, edited):**

```
<form id="myForm">
  <p>What are you searching for?</p>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="contactChoice1" name="contact" value="emergency">
    <label for="contactChoice1">Emergency</label>

    <input type="radio" id="contactChoice2" name="contact" value="vaccination">
    <label for="contactChoice2">Vaccination</label>

    <input type="radio" id="contactChoice3" name="contact" value="bloodtest">
    <label for="contactChoice3">Bloodtest</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" id="submitButton" value="Search"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var form = document.getElementById('myForm');

var reroute = function() {
  event.preventDefault;
  var selectValue = form.querySelector("input:checked").value;
  if (selectValue) window.open('https://mydomain.test/' + selectValue); 
}

document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click', reroute, false);
```

working example [here on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HynekS/mdw5fdjy/)